# How to return view with curl array

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm making a cURL request to another server and retrieving an array from there. From a normal php page, by pressing the button a jQuery request goes through to my Controller and I should return the cURL array I'm recieving to a another page. I'm using `return view` but it does nothing.

I've tried with return Response

```
return Response::json(array(
            'success'       => true,
            'message'   => "listing",
            'list' => $listing,

            ));
```

And also with

```
return view('page2', ['list' => $listing]);
```

Here is the Controller function

```
public function listStuff(Request $request){

            $url = 'http://someting.com/rest.php';
            $params = array('action' => 'list', 'token' => 'xxx');

            $session = curl_init($url);


            curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);

            curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

            curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $response = curl_exec($session);

            $listing = $response;


            curl_close($session);

            Debugbar::info($listing);
            return view('page2', ['list' => $listing]);


    }
```

I have checked with debugbar that array comes through. If I try to change the view with `return view` and passing the array the view doesn't load up.

Comment: try using guzzle library

Comment: Try Return Redirect?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest JSON as it's easy to start with.So try someting like this

```
$listing= json_decode(trim($p_result), TRUE);
return view('page2', ['list' => $listing]);
```